# Generate functor with shared_from_this

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, variadic-templates

I'd like to create a functor from a class A that inherits from enable_shared_from_this, that is for a class like this:

```
class A: public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    ...
}
```

I want to have a member function that looks something like this (incorrect code):

```
template <typename Args...>
std::function<void(Args ...)> functor_from_this(void (A::*method)(Args...)) {
    return std::bind(method, shared_from_this());
}
```

The code above generates several errors, starting with `warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored`, which makes me suspect I'm going about this the wrong way. How do I go about achieving something like this?

Extra credits for (a) binding the Args... to the functor as well so I get a function whose signature is `void fn()`, and (b) doing all this in a general-purpose class that inherits from `enable_shared_from_this<T>`.

Comment: *"Extra credits for ...."* - How do we earn the extra credits. :-)

Comment: Please include the error messages you refer to.

Comment: @molbdnilo fair enough!

Comment: @WhiZTiM I guess you can make me to open follow up questions instead of answering here. ;)

Comment: And some indication of what those error messages refer to, of course. That one looks entirely unrelated to that code (which is missing a `return`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I can do that, but I get about 50 lines of errors, so I really think my approach is what's wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for C++14 the solution is [easy enough to write](http://ideone.com/ml8EpV). Just forgo `std::bind` and return a lambda instead:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A: std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {

    template <typename... Args>
    std::function<void(Args...)> functor_from_this(void (A::*method)(Args...)) {
        return [=, obj = shared_from_this()](Args... args) {
          ((*obj).*method)(args...);
        };
    }

    void foo(int) { std::cout << "foo" << '\n'; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
  auto a = std::make_shared<A>();

  auto f = a->functor_from_this(&A::foo);
  auto b = a->functor_from_this(&A::bar);

  f(1);
  b();
}
```

For C++11 as Jarod42 pointed out in a comment, use a much simpler intermediate variable:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A: std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {

    template <typename... Args>
    std::function<void(Args...)> functor_from_this(void (A::*method)(Args...)) {
        auto obj = shared_from_this();
        return [=](Args... args) {
          ((*obj).*method)(args...);
        };
    }

    void foo(int) { std::cout << "foo" << '\n'; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
  auto a = std::make_shared<A>();

  auto f = a->functor_from_this(&A::foo);
  auto b = a->functor_from_this(&A::bar);

  f(1);
  b();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the book available - care to expand on this?

Comment: @nitzanms - I'm on it. I don't have the book myself, and it's a bit tedious to recollect :)

Comment: For C++11 solution, use intermediate varaible: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ee8b92afe47b9ba)

Comment: @nitzanms - You have your (much simpler) solution, courtesy of Jarod.

Answer (score 1):

For extra credit (B), here is the solution I found, based on the answer by StoryTeller & Jarod:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
class enable_functor_from_this: public std::enable_shared_from_this<T> {
    public:
    template <typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) functor_from_this(void (T::*method)(Args...)) {
        auto obj = this->shared_from_this();
        return [=](Args... args) {
          ((*obj).*method)(args...);
        };
    }
};

struct A: enable_functor_from_this<A> {
    void foo(int) { std::cout << "foo" << '\n'; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
  auto a = std::make_shared<A>();

  auto f = a->functor_from_this(&A::foo);
  auto b = a->functor_from_this(&A::bar);

  f(1);
  b();
}
```